# resolve url to get the actual page of website?

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

i came across this kind of URL http://www.ukbidz.com/Baby,category,1889,parent_id,categories
actually this URL is not generated by me.

I want to some changes in it, and i am unable to locate the page from where the data is coming. So i need to know is there any way to find the page from the data is coming, so that i can do the changes. I have all the pages but i am unable to find the page to do changes. Please Help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: check to see if there's an .htaccess file you can examine. Something's rewriting your urls and we won't be able to tell what from this site.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any kind of client-side framework or is it pure php?

I want to say to check out `mod_rewrite` with the **.htaccess** file.  [Here is a doc](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/modrewrite-tips-tricks.html), but there a handfull of other blogs explaining how you can use mod_rewrite to create dynamic links, and which php pages are associated with it.

Comment: You want to look for the .htaccess file, sometimes it is a hidden file, so you may need to show all file types in your operating system [if you are running this locally].  Usually it is in the root of the application.

Comment: seen .htaccess file, but nothing there in it.